# Kivy App : Set Resolution and Scale it up to screen size not working

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I tried to fix the resolution in kivy and scale it up to android

I tried around but nothing seems to work

```
def build(self):
    Window.height: 1000
    Window.width: 600
    Window.fullscreen: '1'

    return FloatLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue with

```
 allow_stretch: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dimens.xml folder and declare the dimen in each of your object.

Dimens.xml